# Uipopover frame reset on orientation without hiding or dismissing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

**Presented Popover on Video Button Tap:**

```
[self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self.view convertRect:buttonFrame toView:self.view.window]
                                                inView:self.view.window
                              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                              animated:YES];
```

`videoButton` is a button from which the popover pops up. Now the problem is, when I rotate my device, The popover remains on the position it was drawn while the rest of the view adjusts according to the rotation. In simple words, when device is rotated with the popover drawn (popping up from `UIButton`), the popover doesn't move along with the `UIButton`. If I close the popover and again draw it from the button, It draws correctly above the button. The problem only comes when rotating with the popover popped up.

On orientation,　I want to change the frame position rather than dismissing it and presenting it again. How can I do it this way?

Comment: The only way to achieve that without dismissing it and presenting it again is to set the autoresizing mask for your button. It 'll definitely work out.

Answer (score 0):

You can call present popover method again on will change orientation method.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    [self.popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[self.view convertRect:buttonFrame toView:self.view.window] inView:self.view.window permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I don't want to call it again ,because i am uploading video through this popover ,it's creating problem when the video takes time for compressing,on rotation if i create again popover then it doesn't dismiss the previous popover and if i dismiss then compressing video couldn't get.  So, I want same popover on the orientation which is compressing video for upload on my journalviewController

Comment: I think i did not understand your concern, But if you are bothered about the reinitialisation of Popover that will not happen as we are just presenting it again.

Comment: On the video compressing time ,If we present new popover without dismissing previous one,then it's randomly crashing,because of the presenting popovers again and again. So, i want to change the popover frame only,not to present and dismiss it.

Comment: What does crash report says?? if it is crashing you should find the cause of crash not the work around.

Comment: It's crashing because of presenting popover every time in orientation change,when we change it again and again ,means every time new popover presenting without dismissing previous popovers. If it's doesn't crashes then after video compressing ,means last one presenting popover is dismissed and after it when i change orientation ,the remaining popover comes one by one